# How to play 360 video using libvlc using VLC Player in iOS

Tags: ios, vlc, libvlc, lib, panoramas

im creating an iOS Application, where i have to play 360 video using VLCPlayer. I have added VLC via pod, and played a 360 video locally. But VLC not being able to pan the video. VLC doesn't treat video as 360 video. Should i make many settings to play 360 video using VLC?

Sample 360 video URL https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TzoxrWMdiLBuf5TTq0v6lz-KNtxeMOb2/view

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "rico", ofType:"mov") else {
        debugPrint("video.m4v not found")
        return
    }
    mediaURL = path
    setupMediaPLayer()
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    mediaPlayer.play()
}
func setupMediaPLayer() {
    mediaPlayer.delegate = self
    mediaPlayer.drawable = movieView
    mediaPlayer.media = VLCMedia(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: mediaURL!))
}
```

Comment: Is your video tagged correctly? Does it contain 360 metadata?

Comment: yes. its working fine with vlc app downloaded from app store. When i given the same video as a file path to vlc player integrated via cocoapod, its playing like normal video.

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Not in the comment, in your original question. And with code formatting please... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yes i have edited the question, Please check

Comment: The above video working fine with VLC downloaded from Appstore.But not working as 360 when playing with VLC library integrated via cocoapod.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` yourself for 360 videos.

```
- (void)handlePinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGFloat diff = DEFAULT_FOV * -(ZOOM_SENSITIVITY * recognizer.velocity / _screenPixelSize.width);

    if ([_vpc currentMediaIs360Video]) {
        [self zoom360Video:diff];
    } else if (recognizer.velocity < 0. && _closeGestureEnabled) {
        [self minimizePlayback:nil];
    }
}
```

See this code for an example https://github.com/videolan/vlc-ios/blob/eab270fb5cf9622386aef7040113e9b37fe2406f/Sources/VLCMovieViewController.m#L783